# What process API do I need to hook to track services?

Tags: windows, windows-services

I need to track to a log when a service or application in Windows is started, stopped, and whether it exits successfully or with an error code.

I understand that many services do not log their own start and stop times, or if they exit correctly, so it seems the way to go would have to be inserting a hook into the API that will catch when services/applications request a process space and relinquish it.

My question is what function do I need to hook in order to accomplish this, and is it even possible?  I need it to work on Windows XP and 7, both 64-bit.

Comment: This should probably be in stackoverflow rather than superuser, since it is a programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your best bet is to use a device driver.  See [PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559951%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Windows Vista has [`NotifyServiceStatusChange()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684276%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), but only for single services. On earlier versions, it's not possible other than polling for changes or watching the event log.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a user-space solution, EnumProcesses() will return a current list.  But it won't signal you with changes, you'd have to continually poll it and act on the differences.

If you're watching for a specific application or set of applications, consider assigning them to Job Objects, which are all about allowing you to place limits on processes and manage them externally. I think you could even associate Explorer with a job object, then all tasks launched by the user would be associated with your job object automatically.  Something to look into, perhaps.